# Java trying change the variable value within a method and constructor

Tags: java

The code that i've written works like this:
There is a Superhero class, with instance variables, two constructors, (a possibly faulty method called powerUp) and a method to initiate a fight between two object instances.

When i run my code i am getting the following output from command line:

> Cyclops 10
>   Colossus 40
>   The winner is: Colossus
>   After receiving a power-up: Cyclops has a Strength of: 50
>   Testing the Cyclops strength: 50
>   The winner is: Colossus

After the first "The winner is Colossus" it should be Cyclops as the winner as this object instance receives a powerUp of 100 which is a boost of 40 strength, however for some reason this rule does not get applied and the code says Colossus is still the winner.. the program calculates the winner based on the strength, the highest is the winner, or if they are both equal the opponent is the winner.

The code is displayed below.

Super hero class:

```
public class Superhero{

//private instance variables declared below
//name of the super hero
private String name;
//name of the strength variable
private int strength;
//The variable for the powerUp method
private int powerUp;
//variable to store the power of the power up
private int storePower;



//Getter methods
public int getStrength(){
    return strength;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}










//constructor for if the player wanted to specify the name and the strength
public Superhero(String name, int strength){
    this.name = name;
    this.strength = strength;

    System.out.println(name + " " + strength);
}



//if the user doesn't enter the strength as it is optional
//this constructor below will run and set the default
public Superhero(String name){
    this.name = name;
    this.strength = 10;
    System.out.println(name + " " + strength );

}


/*
This method takes in an integer paremeter and based on that it does
some calculations.

There are four possible integer values you can pass in: 100, 75, 50 and 25.

If 100 has been passed in the storePower variable is set to 40 which would be
a power-up of 40, if 75 then power-up of 30, if 50 then a power-up of 20,
if 25 then a power-up of 10 and if the right ammount is not specified a power-up
of 0 will be assigned.

*/
public void powerUp(int powerUp){
    this.powerUp = powerUp;
    if(powerUp == 100){
        strength = strength + 40;
    }else if(powerUp == 75){
        strength = strength + 30;
    }else if(powerUp == 50){
        strength = strength + 20;
    }else if(powerUp == 25){
        strength = strength + 10;
    }else{
        strength = strength + 0;
    }
    this.strength = strength + storePower;
    System.out.println("After receiving a power-up: " + name +  " has a Strength of: " + strength);


}


//the method for fight
public Superhero fight(Superhero opponent) {
  if (this.getStrength() > opponent.getStrength()){
    return this;
  }else if(this.getStrength() == opponent.getStrength()){
    return opponent;
  }else{
    return opponent;
  }
}
```

}

Fight class:

```
public class Fight{
public static void main(String[] args){

    // a. Create a Superhero named Cyclops
    Superhero Cyclops = new Superhero("Cyclops");

    //b. Create a Superhero named Colossus. Colossus has a strength of 40
    Superhero Colossus = new Superhero("Colossus", 40);

    //c. Make Cyclops fight Colossus. Print the winner to the terminal.
    Superhero winner = Cyclops.fight(Colossus);
    System.out.println("The winner is: " + winner.getName());

    //d. Give Cyclops a powerUp of 100
    Cyclops.powerUp(100);

    //e. Make Cyclops fight Colossus. Print the winner to the terminal.
    Superhero winner2 = Cyclops.fight(Colossus);
    System.out.println("Testing the Cyclops strength: " + Cyclops.getStrength());
    System.out.println("The winner is: " + winner.getName());


}
```

}

During debugging i have tried everything i can possibly think of i have changed up this code below:

```
public void powerUp(int powerUp){
    this.powerUp = powerUp;
    if(powerUp == 100){
        strength = strength + 40;
    }else if(powerUp == 75){
        strength = strength + 30;
    }else if(powerUp == 50){
        strength = strength + 20;
    }else if(powerUp == 25){
        strength = strength + 10;
    }else{
        strength = strength + 0;
    }
    this.strength = strength;
    System.out.println("After receiving a power-up: " + name +  " has a Strength of: " + strength);


}
```

with

```
    public void powerUp(int powerUp){
    this.powerUp = powerUp;
    if(powerUp == 100){
        storePower = 40;
    }else if(powerUp == 75){
        storePower = 30;
    }else if(powerUp == 50){
        storePower = 20;
    }else if(powerUp == 25){
        storePower = 10;
    }else{
        storePower = 0;
    }
    this.strength = strength + storePower;
    System.out.println("After receiving a power-up: " + name +  " has a Strength of: " + strength);


}
```

and nothing seems to change, for some reason Cyclops will not be set to that value of 50.

Comment: You seem to be using two variables for `powerUp`, `powerUp` and `storePower`, but `storePower` is never updated and is always `0`

Comment: How would i be able to update store power?

Comment: Do you really need to?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling getName() on winner, shouldn't it be winner2.

```
Superhero winner2 = Cyclops.fight(Colossus);
    System.out.println("Testing the Cyclops strength: " + Cyclops.getStrength());
    System.out.println("The winner is: " + winner.getName());
```